# Radio | Is there a way how to align an icon horizontally using just props, without styles

Tags: reactjs, mantine

Is there a way how to align an icon horizontally using just props, without styles

Code - https://codesandbox.io/s/smoosh-hill-nr230p?file=/src/App.js:113-349

There you go:

```
export default function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Radio
                label="I cannot be unchecked"
                // How to align horizontally?
                icon={() => <IconAdjustments size={18} color='red'/>}
            />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`icon` property is used to change the icon of the `Radio` button itself. If you want to add icon to the label, you should use:

```
<Radio
    label={
        <>
            <IconAdjustments size={14} color="red" />
            I cannot be unchecked
        </>
    }  
/>
```

### Edit:

As for now it is still not clear what you want to achieve after all, so here are all the possible scenarios.

1. If you want icon in the label => the solution above.
2. If you want to change the icon in the radio button itself:

- You either provide the icon element itself => `icon={IconAdjustments}` or..
- You provide a react component **that accepts `className` as a property** and applies it to the returned element:

```
icon={({ className }) => (
    <IconAdjustments className={className} color="red" />
)}
```

Passing `size` to the tabler icon element won't work for you as size is calculated internally based on the `size` of the `Radio` button and fixed `width` and `height` are applied to the icon.

Comment: Yeah, it's a way, thank you. In truth, I've had this option. There is a wish to use the icon prop

Comment: @HackerMF I don't understand. What are you trying to do after all?

Comment: Just understand there is a chanсe to use the prop icon for this case –

Comment: No, there is no chance. Like I told you already, the `icon` property is used to change the dot inside the `Radio` button.

Comment: No, it's not for that. Look at my codesandbox. There is still the dot in the  radio

Comment: @HackerMF Because you aren't even using it properly. You have to pass an SVG element, not a function. It should be: `icon={IconAdjustments}`. Furthermore, it is clearly stated in the docs: https://mantine.dev/core/radio/?t=props

Comment: Try to use it properly as u think. U'll see what u will get. Yeah, right it's clear stated in the docs, FC<Pick<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>

Comment: @HackerMF It is not about what I think, it is about what IT IS. I tell you how it is working and how it is supposed to be used and I give you concrete example on how to achieve the thing you want. You're just ignorant and don't want to face the facts. Good luck then.

Comment: FC<Pick<SVGProps<SVGSVGElement> I guess u don't understand what it means, that's why u think that is about what IT IS. Nice.
Try to use your example using my codesandbox and I hope U will understand something

Comment: @HackerMF There is a difference between a function and a react component, my man. Instead of being toxicly arrogant, appreciate the help you get. I'll make an edit to the post so you can understand the issue better.

Comment: it's not the toxic arrogant. I've just tried as u said before and there were not any changes, then I tried to add just svg and nothing, so  I thought you didn't try it but advised it, Now I checked it then  I click radio and noticed that the icon was inside of radio. Apologies, my bad